# entity framework reusing edmx entity connection string

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, web-config, edmx

Trying to understand entity framework and the edmx files generated.

While adding a edmx file to my solution it adds the following section

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.MyModel.csdl|
res://*/Model.MyModel.ssdl|
res://*/Model.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection 
string=&quot;Server=xxx;Database=mydb;
UserID=xxxx;Password=xx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Everything works fine until I need to delete the edmx and re-add it. Leaving the above config section intact AND choosing to skip the 
"Save entity connection settings in web.config as: MyEntities" causes issues.

The solution no longer recognizes my object context - MyEntities. It gives me a generic "Entities" instead. I check the designer.cs file and it sure enough 
its peppered with Entities instead of MyEntities. Would be great if someone could throw some light on how this mapping works and how everytime I delete and re-add the same edmx I would not have to edit the config file.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question? I've just started looking into EF and I too was initially perplexed that if I didn't store the connection settings in web.config, it renamed by object context "Entities" instead... is there a way to rename this?

Answer (score 0):

before you readd the edmx file, just remove(or backup it elsewhere) the <add> section from the config file to reuse the connectionstring name.